# Installing QGIS Server 3.4 on Windows 10

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-server, windows-10

I'm trying to install QGis Server 3.4 on Windows. Apache says "500 Internal Server error" and if I execute `qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe`, I get this:

[image]

(something along the way "can't find entry point for procedure foo in dll bar")

I installed it via OSGeo4W, selecting Desktop->qgis-ltr v3.10.3-1 (which fires up nicely), Libs->fcgi v2.4.1-2, and Web->qgis-ltr-server v3.4.15-1

In case it's some use, here's my PATH:
`C:\OSGeo4W64\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass78\lib;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass78\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\WBem;c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qt5\bin`. Those grass references are about and old QGis Server 2.18 installation, which I totally wiped.

Comment: Execute from the command line. Anyway, I solved it. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working. qgis server and qgis desktop versions must match. I wanted the server to be v3.4, but AFAIK it can't be done, so I installed qgis-ltr-server v3.10.3-1